# Depending on condition insert list of object/ list of custom model in var in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have a condition where I am creating a payload with key value pair and depending of a condition the value will change. How can I achieve this without using `dynamic` as my data type?

```
dynamic finalList;
if(condition)
finalList = new List<object>() {...};
else
finalList = object.ExistingList;
```

I am consuming this finalList as a value in payload.

```
Placeholders = new Dictionary<string, object> {
  { "keyForList", finalList }
}
```

Is there any other way I can achieve above logic without using **dynamic** as my datatype for `finalList` as I don't know future challenges I might face for using it. Also, `finalList` might go under some further computation in future.

Comment: What is the type of `ExistingList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary is defined as `Dictionary<string, object>`. Use an `object` type instead of `dynamic`:

```cs
object finalList = condition 
  ? new List<object>() {...}
  : object.ExistingList;
```

However, I suspect the `object.ExistingList` is an `IEnumerable`. If so, then use the common interface for both lists:

```cs
IEnumerable<object> finalList = condition 
  ? new List<object>() {...}
  : object.ExistingList;
```